# Align something with RelativeLayout in TOP-CENTER

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to center the adMob to the top CENTER. I'm in landscape mode. I decided to keep using BANNER size instead of SMART_BANNER because of the image support in the first one. It keeps showing in TOP LEFT.

I need to achieve it without xml files, using java code. I'm using RelativeLayout.

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mHandle = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if ((String) msg.obj == "hide") {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        };

        RelativeLayout adsLayout;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2;
        Window window;

        window = getWindow();
        adsLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // Displays Ads at the bottom of your sketch, use Gravity.TOP to display
        // them at the top
        adsLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP); // TOP, BOTTOM

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7026369821782045/7333385813");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        adsLayout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("2BC774A37080BC16DF211A91E61710BA")
        .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        window.addContentView(adsLayout, lp2);
    }

    public void hideAds() {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = "hide";
        mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    public void showAds() {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = "show";
        mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Width of the banner will be same as the activity (screen), height will be as tall as it needs to be.

**Remove** `adsLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);`

and use lp2 on the adView, instead of the layout. `adsLayout.addView(adView, lp2);`

also, you dont need `Window` in an Activity, you can use `setContentView(adsLayout);`

Comment: Love you man. It worked.
I needed the Window, because it needs to overlap something.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solved your problem, please consider accepting as answer.

Comment: `lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);` did the trick for me. Thanks.